# Neural Nework and mathematical programming

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models, linear-programming

I am solving a scheduling problem where staff members cannot have overtime. For this problem, I have an integer programming model and solve it using the CPLEX solver. A simplified version of this model looks like the below:

$$\begin{align*}
\min Z &= X C^\mathsf T\\
XB^\mathsf T &\geq b\\
X &\in Z_{\geq0}\end{align*}
$$

Given the complexity of the problem, I would like to approximate the overtime component of the problem for each given solution $X$ (e.g., the number of scheduled patients). For this, I have built a simulation model, run it for several different potential values of $X$ (input values) and calculated the total overtime (output values). Now, I need a way to build a LINEAR approximation equation in $X$ and include it in the above optimization model. One way is to use regression analysis and fit an algebraic model to predict the overtime.

However, I would like to know whether I could use a neural network to derive a linear algebraic equation in $X$ and predict the overtime for different values of $X$? I have found [this article](https://alasko.medium.com/convert-simple-neuron-network-to-mathematician-notation-58a0d72f0337), but it seems that the resulting equations are not linear due to the presence of activation functions. Note that I do not want to use the neural network to solve the problem. I just want to use the neural network to derive a linear algebraic equation in $X$ and include it as a constraint set in the above model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the ReLU activation function and derive a linear equation from a neural network. Further information is presented in [this paper (doi: 10.1007/s10601-018-9285-6)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10601-018-9285-6)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "derive a linear equation from a neural network", but a ReLU neural network doesn't give you a linear map and the paper you refer to is also not claiming that. You get a piecewise linear map.

Comment: When I asked for a linear equation, I was referring to equations that could be incorporated into linear programming. Please see pages 298 and 299 in the paper.

Answer (score 7):

You are right, the activation functions prevent the neural network (NN) from being a linear function, unless you only use linear activation functions, but then it would be again just a linear model. It's this nonlinearity in the activation functions which makes them perform so well in some situations.

If you want to obtain a linear model, you should fit a linear model. Even if you would find a way to use a NN and somehow apply some constraints that makes it learn a linear model, this wouldn't be better, and likely worse, than fitting a linear model.